# Помощь в решении задач по Java

Tags: java, коллекции

Здравствуйте,
Я только начал изучать Java (примерно как месяц) и сейчас застрял на коллекциях. Причём застрял так основательно - с пробуксировкой. Решил написать игрушку консольную "Поле Чудес", но есть запара. Подскажите, подалуйста, форумы, где мне могут помочь.
Не думаю, что кому то из местных захочется разбираться в моём "творчистве", поэтому прошу лишь указать где искать помощи.
В гугле посмотрел, но там то просто статьи с примерами задач, но то какие это уж слишком крутый форумы.
Спасибо.
Cyrus.

**UPD**
Вот у меня в main.java есть кусок:

```
Player player = new Player();
        player.setName("Player1");
        game.AddPlayer();
        player.setLetter('a');
        game.Check();
```

Как из него может быть некоторым понятно происходит слкдующее:
1. создаём объект класса Плеир
2. через сеттер заносим в него имя игрока
3. добавляем игрока в коллекцию (код ниже)
4. игрок вводит букву
5. происходит некая операция с буквой

Теперь "код ниже":

```
void AddPlayer() {
        System.out.println("Регистрирую игрока с id " + globalId);
        playersCollection.put(globalId, player.getName());
        globalId++;
    }
```

Ошибка происходит как раз в третий строчке при попытке внести игрока в коллекцию - NullPointerException, т.е., как я понимаю, из player.getName() нифигашеньки не возвращается, верно?

**UPD2**
Вот инициализация, [[@JEcho](/users/14301/jecho)](/users/14301/jecho)

```
HashMap<Integer, String> playersCollection = new HashMap<>();
Player player;
int globalId = 0;
```

**UPD3**
Вот класс Player, который по нашим ожиданиям "сыпится":

> package main;
>
> /
>
>  *@date Sep 24, 2013* 
>  @author Cyrus S
> */
>
> class Player {
>     private String name;
>     private char letter;
>
> ```
> void setName(String name) {
>     this.name = name; 
> }
>
> String getName() {
>     return name;
> }
>
> void setLetter(char letter) {
>     this.letter = letter; 
> }
>
> char getLetter() {
>     return letter;
> }
> ```
>
> }

Хотя там и сыпаться-то нечему.

Comment: Напишите конкретно какая вам коллекция непонятна - попробуем помочь. Только не надо все валить в кучу - одна коллекция. И не надо лепить много исходников. Попробуйте вкратце и внятно объяснить что непонятно. Если вы внятно объясните что вам непонятно, то вам помогут, а если начнете писать: *млин завтра здавать курсач, препод казёл - поможите!!!!* - вас пошлют и причем далеко

Comment: а можно поподробнее про "рассыпание" player? Что мне стоит проверить, на что заострить внимание?

Comment: player не инициализирован.
int по умолчанию "0" , HashMap, не ругается, если в нее null пихать, т.е. такая конструкция к ошибке не приведет: map.put(null, null); остается player) вообще не показательный код;-) пишите более подробно (но без фанатизма)

Comment: @JEcho, инициальзировал player'a, с инта снял ноль - поезд двинулся, спасибо! А почему с инта нужно было убрать ноль? Потому что при каждом вызове объекта класса Game он обнуляется, верно?

Comment: думаю, ни в нуле дело, он на нпе точно не влиял...вообще без полного кода, что-то сказать, даже не возьмусь, меилафон слоался)...NPE был, потому-что Вы пытались вызвать метод, у объекта null...Вообще могу посоветовать Вам вести отладочную печать и не брезговать стэетрейсом. Успехов)

Comment: Сыпаться тут и правда нечему.

Давайте-ка вы возьмёте отладчик, и скажете, какая именно строка вылетает. Ставлю на то, что ваша переменная, в которой должен быть `Player`, равна `null`.

Comment: К сожалению стуктура кода классов не приведена, но IMHO вот это


    Player player = new Player();
    player.setName("Player1");

локально в main, а вот это

   Player player;
   int globalId = 0;

переменные класса, вот их то метод 

   void AddPlayer()

и видит, а вовсе не ту локальную переменную, что `player.setName("Player1");`

Вот и nullptr.

Соответственно `Player player;` в классе надо убирать, а правильный ответ у @Алексей Алыбин - используйте параметры.

--

По идее, надо бы коллекцию выделить в отдельный класс, а не делать членом класса c main. Иначе вся инкапсуляция насмарку.

Comment: @avp, спасибо большое. как говорил Кот Матроскин: "УРА!ЗАРАБОТАЛО!" :D

Answer (score 3):

Советую переписать функцию добавления игрока, слово 'add' в названии функции предполагает передачу параметров.
Вместо: `game.AddPlayer();` 
Лучше: `game.AddPlayer(player);`

Comment: И заодно перечитать Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language

Comment: это сионисты)..в смысле сишники...у них обычно методы с заглавной))..тоже глаз режет))

Comment: понял. уже читаю.

Answer (score 1):

стэктрейс бы...NullPointerException значит что-то инициализированно..
playersCollection,player,globalId  - где и как инициализируются? 
Npe возникает когда Вы пытаетесь обратиться, к методу не инициализированного объекта, т.е. я почти уверен, что трабла ни в том, что getName возвращает нал, скорее всего сыпится player, на попытке вызвать метод getName, либо playersCollection на попытке дернуть put

Comment: знать бы что такое этот "стэкрейс". в гугле на первых трёх страницах одно и тоже: "вот мой стекрейс", "дай стекрейс", а что это из себя представляет и как его вызывать - не понятно
upd. нашёл. не нужно в русском сегменте искать было.

Comment: стэк вызова....эм...как-бы попроще...а придумал! Та хрень которая пишется когда вываливается ошибка, просто описание ошибки обычно многое может рассказть, кто куда и что впихнул невпихуемое)